# Can someone explain this statement? lpadded = win // 2 * [-1] + l + win // 2 * [-1]

Tags: python

Given that l is a list of integers and win is an integer, the following code produces a list lpadded:

```
lpadded = win // 2 * [-1] + l + win // 2 * [-1]
```

In lpadded -1 is padded to the start and end of the list, but I have absolutely no idea how that code generates this list. What do the [-1]s do with integers here? I have never seen this kind of python syntax before.

Comment: It's a single element list with element being integer of value -1, multiplied by scalar value.

Comment: You should be able to group the sub-expressions using brackets if you know [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Comment: hint: cut the expression in smaller groups, and see what each does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, you can “multiply” a list by an integer to build a list of repeated elements.

```
>>> [42] * 4
[42, 42, 42, 42]
>>> ['hello', 'world'] * 3
['hello', 'world', 'hello', 'world', 'hello', 'world']
```

So the expression `win // 2 * [-1]` creates a `list` object containing `win // 2` copies of the number -1.